# nHibernate 2.0 - mapping a composite-id *and* many-to-one relationship causes "invalid index" error

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a problem.  Imagine this data model:

```
[Person] table has: PersonId, Name1  
[Tag] table has:  TagId, TagDescription  
[PersonTag] has: PersonId, TagId, IsActive
```

Since `[PersonTag]` isn't just a simple many-to-many join table, I have all three entities created in nHibernate (exactly like they are in the data model). `PersonTag`, therefore, needs a composite-id, which I have mapped to a class like this:

```
<composite-id name="PersonTagKey" class="PersonTagKey">
  <key-property name="PersonId"></key-property>
  <key-property name="TagId"></key-property>
</composite-id>
```

I want to traverse the object graph and be able to look at both the `Person` and `Tag` objects from a retrieved `PersonTag` object.  So, I have properties on the `PersonTag` object to do that, mapped like this:

```
<many-to-one name="Person" column="PersonId" lazy="proxy" cascade="none" class="Person"/>
<many-to-one name="Tag" column="TagId" lazy="proxy" cascade="none" class="Tag"/>
```

When I try to create a `PersonTag` object and save it, I get an *"Invalid index n for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=n"* error.  I know this is because I've mapped the `PersonId` and `TagId` properties twice, once for the composite-id, and once for the many-to-one relationship. If I don't map the many-to-one objects, then everything works fine.

*Is there some way for me to be able to have a composite-id AND a many-to-one relationship based on the same column modeled in the same nHibernate entity?*

Comment: BTW, i just came across the "key-many-to-one" subelement in composite-id... might that be it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Kay, here's the answer.  Little-to-no documentation on this:

```
<composite-id name="PersonTagKey" class="PersonTagKey"> 
  <key-many-to-one name="Person" column="PersonId" lazy="proxy" class="Person">
  <key-many-to-one name="Tag" column="TagId" lazy="proxy" class="Tag"/>
</composite-id>
```

This will allow you to create a composite-id made up of the inverse of a many-to-one relationship.

Good hunting...

Comment: You're bang on about there being hardly any documentation on this! Could you clarify something for me a bit? What were the final class definitions like? are they 

class Person{ ISet<PersonTag> PersonTags; } 

class Tag { ISet<PersonTag> PersonTags; } 

class PersonTag { PersonTagKey Key; bool IsActive; } 

class PersonTagKey { Person Person; Tag Tag; }

Comment: You got it!  Only difference was that I was using List<T>, not ISet<T>.  That end up working for you?

Comment: Many many thanks for discovering this - I just rammed headlong into it.  It looks like *everything* is required to be objects.  FYI for future searchers: you can add criterion restrictions by specifying the complete path to the relevant sub-object values: `Restrictions.Eq("PersonTagKey.Person.Id", 123)`