# Why can't I reference child entities with part of the parent entities composite key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate, composite-id

I am trying to reference some child entities with part of the parents composite key not all of it, why cant I? This happens when I use the following mapping instead of that which is commented.

I get the following error

> Foreign key in table
>   VolatileEventContent must have same
>   number of columns as referenced
>   primary key in table
>   LocationSearchView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="JeanieMaster.Domain.Entities" assembly="JeanieMaster.Domain">
  <class name="LocationSearchView" table="LocationSearchView">

    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="LocationId" type="Int32"></key-property>
      <key-property name="ContentProviderId" type="Int32"></key-property>
      <key-property name="CategoryId" type="Int32"></key-property>
    </composite-id>

    <property name="CompanyName" type="String" not-null="true" update="false" insert="false"/>
    <property name="Description" type="String" not-null="true" update="false" insert="false"/>
    <property name="CategoryId" type="Int32" not-null="true" update="false" insert="false"/>
    <property name="ContentProviderId" type="Int32" not-null="true" update="false" insert="false"/>
    <property name="LocationId" type="Int32" not-null="true" update="false" insert="false"/>
    <property name="Latitude" type="Double"  update="false" insert="false" />
    <property name="Longitude" type="Double"  update="false" insert="false" />

    <bag name="Events" table="VolatileEventContent" where="DeactivatedOn IS NULL" order-by="StartDate DESC" lazy="false" cascade="none">
      <key>
        <column name="LocationId"></column>
        <column name="ContentProviderId"></column>
        <!--<column name="LocationId"></column>
        <column name="ContentProviderId"></column>
        <column name="CategoryId"></column>-->
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="Event" column="VolatileEventContentId"></one-to-many>
    </bag>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And VolatileEventContent mapping file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="JeanieMaster.Domain.Entities" assembly="JeanieMaster.Domain">
  <class name="Event" table="VolatileEventContent" select-before-update="false" optimistic-lock="none">
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="LocationId" type="Int32"></key-property>
      <key-property name="ContentProviderId" type="Int32"></key-property>
    </composite-id>

    <property name="Description" type="String" not-null="true" update="false" insert="false"/>

    <property name="StartDate" type="DateTime" not-null="true" update="false" insert="false" />
    <property name="EndDate" type="DateTime" not-null="true" update="false" insert="false" />

    <property name="CreatedOn" type="DateTime" not-null="true" update="false" insert="false" />
    <property name="ModifiedOn" type="DateTime" not-null="false" update="false" insert="false" />

    <many-to-one name="Location" class="Location" column="LocationId" />

    <bag name="Artistes" table="EventArtiste" lazy="false" cascade="none">
      <key name="VolatileEventContentId" />
      <many-to-many class="Artiste" column="ArtisteId" ></many-to-many>
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Could you post your mapping of `VolatileEventContent` too?

Comment: Added additional mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is correct.  I'm guessing that you are using `SchemaExport` to generate your tables based on the NHibernate mappings, since the error you are receiving sounds like it would occur during the creation of your tables and foreign keys.  `SchemaExport` would produce tables similar to the following (please note the explanations scattered throughout the code):

```
CREATE TABLE LocationSearchView (
    LocationId int NOT NULL,
    ContentProviderId int NOT NULL,
    CategoryId int NOT NULL,

    /* ...other columns... */

    /* Note: Generated from LocationSearchView's "composite-id" element.  */
    PRIMARY KEY (LocationId, ContentProviderId, CategoryId)
);

/* Note: Table for the "Event" class. */
CREATE TABLE VolatileEventContent (
    LocationId int NOT NULL,
    ContentProviderId int NOT NULL,

    /* ...other columns... */

    /* Note: Generated from Event's "composite-id" element. */
    PRIMARY KEY (LocationId, ContentProviderId),
    /* Note: Generated from the "key" element of LocationSearchView's Events bag. */
    FOREIGN KEY (LocationId, ContentProviderId) REFERENCES LocationSearchView (LocationId, ContentProviderId)
);
```

... hence the error.  A foreign key must point to a complete primary or unique key - not just part of a primary key.  The whole key is 3 columns, not 2.  Why would NHibernate use those columns for the foreign key?  Because of the `<key>` element of `LocationSearchView`'s `Events` bag.  `<key>` specifies which columns from the *child* point back to the *parent*.

Let's consider what might happen when you (or NHibernate) try to select from these tables.  Assume the following data:

```
TABLE LocationSearchView
LocationId ContentProviderId CategoryId
========== ================= ==========
1          3                 5
1          3                 6
1          4                 5
1          4                 6
2          3                 5
2          3                 6
2          4                 5
2          4                 6
```

```
TABLE VolatileEventContent
LocationId ContentProviderId
========== =================
1          3
1          4
2          3
2          4
```

It is not possible for "one" `LocationSearchView` to have "many" `Event`s.  Rather, it should be the other way around.  Given these tables, there is really a one-to-many relationship from `Event` to `LocationSearchView`.

I don't know what the correct solution to this problem is, because I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, but hopefully this helps to illuminate what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel the hbm files are representative of my tables, Im not using SchemaExport (whatever that is) it is the relationship of the Event to the LocationSearchView I have a problem with

Comment: SchemaExport is a tool that generates tables based on your NHibernate mappings.  I assumed that you were using it because "Foreign key ... must have same number of columns..." sounds like an error that would occur during the creation of the tables and foreign keys.  Could you provide the stack trace for this error?  Are my guesses about your table structure incorrect?  I'll update my answer to explain why I thought your tables look like that.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used nhibernate, but i guess mapping is quite similar the hibernate ones.

If you don't want your one-to-many (LocationSearchView to many VolatileEventContent) association to use the LocationSearchView id, you need to define on the key element of the bag the attribute "property-ref" that will define the property to use instead :

```
<bag name="Events" table="VolatileEventContent" ...>
  <key property-ref="partialId">
    <column name="LocationId"></column>
    <column name="ContentProviderId"></column>
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="Event" column="VolatileEventContentId"></one-to-many>
</bag>
```

(column attribute is valid on a one-to-many tag ?)

Now you need to define a property of that name, something like that :

```
<properties name="partialId" insert="false" update="false">
  <property name="LocationId" type="Int32" update="false" insert="false"/>
  <property name="ContentProviderId" type="Int32" update="false" insert="false"/>
</properties>
```

You have already defined LocationId and ContentProviderId. Just move the these two properties inside the properties element.

Comment: Unfortunately property-ref isnt a recognised attribute :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have an error in your mapping for "`LocationSearchView`"
You define the `CategoryId` column both as a Property and part of the Composite-id. This is wrong but unfortunately it is not caught when building the mapping and is usually exposed when querying the object. check [IndexOutOfRangeException Deep in the bowels of NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298026/indexoutofrangeexception-deep-in-the-bowels-of-nhibernate/2311256#2311256)

It could be confusing the mapping parser. And i am saying **confusing** because in both your mappings you rely on Reflection and Convention which imply a more disciplined programming methodology:

1. You don't explicitly define the `class` attribute of the `many-to-one` and `bag` elements but instead you expect from NHibernate to detect the class type from the class definition itself. If by any chance you have set in the class `LocationSearchView` the following `IList<LocationSearchView> Events {get;set;}` nhibernate would expect to find the `LocationSearchView` class for the defined `bag` and hence require the 3 columns to map the collection
2. You have the same property names for the column names which makes development easier (it actually only makes easier the creation of mappings which you only make once or twice anyway) but in case of errors or changes it makes it harder to detect what went wrong.

So, make your mappings richer and remove the error i mentioned with `CategoryId`, also include the classes in your post!