# Problems updating an NHibernate model object with the contents of a DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, webforms, asp.net-4.5

I'm new to NHibernate but have a better understanding of EF4.

I have a basic "Edit Item" page, and on submit I want to update my Item object with values from the form. FWIW, I'm using a FormView and leveraging the new WebForms Model Binding features where practical.

My "Item" object has a property:

```
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

which corresponds to a FK relationship in the database (column "CategoryId" pointing to table "Category".)

So my form has a "Category" dropdown.  This dropdown has been loaded with a list of all the Category objects.

On submit, all I want to do is assign the selected value in the Category dropdown to the Category property of my Item object.  Pretty straight forward, right?  :)

However I ran into difficulty:

- I can easily get the dropdown.SelectedValue, but I can't assign this to my Item object.  In EF4, my Item object would use a [Foreign Key Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275) and would thererfore have both `Category` and `CategoryId` properties, which would automatically be kept in sync.  When I tried something similar in NHibernate I got a [Invalid Index for this SqlParameterCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888089/invalid-index-n-for-this-sqlparametercollection-with-count-n-or-foreign-key-c) error due to the attempted multiple use of a single column.
- I an easily get the dropdown.SelectedItem, but this is of type [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx), which cannot be cast to `Category`.
- I tried making use of the dropdown.DataSource property (maybe accessing the "SelectedIndex-th" item), but when stepping through the code, this DataSource value was null.

My best (awful) solution so far is as follows:

```
var dropdown = (DropDownList)MyFormView.FindControl("dropdown");
var id = dropdown.SelectedValue;
var category = new MyRepository().GetCategoryById(id);
item.Category = category;
```

So I'm making an extra repository call, and getting the entire Category object again, when all I really want to do is:

```
item.CategoryId = id;
```

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Session.Load](http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id) when you know the id to avoid a trip to the database. Load will create a dynamic proxy and allow the item to be persisted with the correct CategoryId. Load is the best solution in stateless applications.

```
var dropdown = (DropDownList)MyFormView.FindControl("dropdown");
var id = dropdown.SelectedValue; // may need to cast to int
item.Category = session.Load<Category>(id);
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie #2: this approach is similar to what I've already got, though I now (partially :) understand the differences between "Get" and "Load".  In my situation (with "Session-per-request") there are no "Category" values in the current session at the time of postback.  So it is still making a database hit to retrieve the full Category object, when all I want to do is set the CategoryId (which I already have) on the "item" object.

Comment: Load should do that. However, I'm seeing in my own code that it sometimes still hits the database. There are two reasons I know if when this will occur: lazy loading is disabled or a property other than the id is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to get the category object, you can just create a new category object and dynamically set the id.

```
var dropdown = (DropDownList)MyFormView.FindControl("dropdown");
var id = dropdown.SelectedValue;
item.Category = new Category { CategoryId = id };
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie #1, though it didn't work for me.  First error: "object references an unsaved transient instance". I then added "cascade=All" to the FK definition in my HBM. This gave a second error: "could not insert: [Category#MyID]".... NH is interpreting your "new Category {}" statement as a request to insert.