# NHibernate Entity with Composite-Id Saving Issue

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In order to make myself clear, I have created a most basic case to describe my problem. Let's say I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [ProductID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ProductID] ASC )
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderHeader](
    [HeaderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Comment] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderHeader] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [HeaderID] ASC )
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetail](
    [HeaderID] [int] NOT NULL, /* FK to OrderHeader table */
    [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL, /* FK to Product table */
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [HeaderID] ASC, 
    [ProductID] ASC 
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And I have created correponding entity classes and mapping classes.

```
public class Product {
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product> {
    public ProductMap() {
        Table("Product");

        Id(x => x.Id, "ProductID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Name, "ProductName");
    }
}

public class OrderHeader {
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<OrderDetail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class OrderHeaderMap : ClassMap<OrderHeader> {
    public OrderHeaderMap() {
        Table("OrderHeader");

        Id(x => x.Id, "HeaderID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Comment, "Comment");

        HasMany<OrderDetail>(x => x.Details)
            .KeyColumn("HeaderID")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade
            .All();
    }
}

public class OrderDetail {
    public virtual OrderHeader OrderHeader { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        OrderDetail other = obj as OrderDetail;
        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return this.Product.Id == other.Product.Id && this.OrderHeader.Id == other.OrderHeader.Id;
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return (OrderHeader.Id.ToString() + "|" + Product.Id.ToString()).GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class OrderDetailMap : ClassMap<OrderDetail> {
    public OrderDetailMap() {
        Table("OrderDetail");

        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.Product, "ProductID")
            .KeyReference(x => x.OrderHeader, "HeaderID");

        References<OrderHeader>(x => x.OrderHeader, "HeaderID").ForeignKey().Not.Nullable().Fetch.Join();
        References<Product>(x => x.Product, "ProductID").ForeignKey().Not.Nullable();

        Version(x => x.CreatedOn).Column("CreatedOn").Generated.Always();
    }
}
```

I have also created NH Session Provider

```
public class NHibernateSessionProvider {
    private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory {
        get {
            if (sessionFactory == null) {
                sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
            }
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    private static ISessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ShowSql()
            .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("TestDB")))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<OrderHeaderMap>())
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

And a NH repository class is also created

```
public class NHibernateRepository<T, TId> {
        protected ISession session = null;
        protected ITransaction transaction = null;

        public NHibernateRepository() {
            this.session = NHibernateSessionProvider.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        public void Save(T entity) {
            session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
        }

        public void AddNew(T entity) {
            session.Save(entity);
        }

        public void BeginTransaction() {
            transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
        }

        public void CommitTransaction() {
            transaction.Commit();
            closeTransaction();
        }

        public void RollbackTransaction() {
            transaction.Rollback();
            closeTransaction();
            closeSession();
        }

        private void closeTransaction() {
            transaction.Dispose();
            transaction = null;
        }

        private void closeSession() {
            session.Close();
            session.Dispose();
            session = null;
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            if (transaction != null) {
                CommitTransaction();
            }

            if (session != null) {
                session.Flush();
                closeSession();
            }
        }
    }
```

In my code, I have created 2 different ways to save this master/detail structure with composite-id.

```
    private static void method1() {
        NHibernateRepository<Product, int?> repoProduct = new NHibernateRepository<Product, int?>();
        NHibernateRepository<OrderHeader, int?> repo = new NHibernateRepository<OrderHeader, int?>();
        OrderHeader oh = new OrderHeader();
        oh.Comment = "Test Comment " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        oh.Details = new List<OrderDetail>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            oh.Details.Add(new OrderDetail
            {
                OrderHeader = oh,
                Product = repoProduct.GetById(i + 3)
            });
        }

        repo.AddNew(oh);
    }

    private static void method2() {
        NHibernateRepository<OrderHeader, int?> repoHeader = new NHibernateRepository<OrderHeader, int?>();
        OrderHeader oh = new OrderHeader();
        oh.Comment = "Test Comment " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        repoHeader.Save(oh);

        NHibernateRepository<OrderDetail, int?> repoDetail = new NHibernateRepository<OrderDetail, int?>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            OrderDetail od = new OrderDetail
            {
                OrderHeaderId = oh.Id,
                OrderHeader = oh,
                ProductId = i + 3,
                Product = new Product
                {
                    Id = i + 3
                },
            };

            repoDetail.AddNew(od);
        }
    }
```

But for both methods, the OrderDetail table is never saved. I have turned on ShowSql() to see SQL statement executed on console, no SQL generated to save OrderDetail table at all.

I did quite a lot of search everywhere and could not have a clear conclusion what is wrong.

Anybody has some clue, what exactly do I need to do to save an entity with composite-id?

Thanks

Hardy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the model and the mapping are incorrect.

Remove **OrderHeaderId** and **ProductId** from **OrderDetail**.

Then, the Composite id should include **OrderHeader** and **Product** as references (I think with Fluent it's `KeyReference` instead of `KeyProperty`; in XML it's `key-many-to-one` instead of `key-property`)

Then, add a proper `Cascade` setting, as Cole suggested.

Sample usage:

```
using (var session = GetSessionFromSomewhere())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var orderHeader = new OrderHeader();
    ...
    orderHeader.Details.Add(new OrderDetail
                            {
                                OrderHeader = orderHeader;
                                Product = session.Load<Product>(someProductId);
                            });
    session.Save(orderHeader);
    tx.Commit();
}
```

Everything in that block is **required**.

Comment: I tried, it still does not generate insert statement against my OrderDetail table.

Comment: @hardywang: See added example. Your code has several issues too.

Comment: @Diego, I have updated code in my original post to combine your suggestion, I still could not get OrderDetail saved, no SQL statement is generated at all.

Comment: @Diego, update - if I don't nest inside a transaction, no OrderDetail is saved, if I start transaction I get "Invalid index 2 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=2." error message when transaction is being committed. I will do more investigation.

Comment: @hardywang, Check my comment above in my post.

Comment: @Diego/@Cole, thank for both of your help! Code works, I just don't understand one thing is that why Version mapping in OrderDetail will cause some weired behavior (see my comment to Cole's post).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the composite-id is what is causing you issues.  I think it's the way you have your OrderDetails mapped in your OrderHeader map.

I think it should be something like this instead:

```
HasMany<OrderDetail>(x => x.Details).KeyColumn("HeaderID").Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

**Edit:**

You should listen to Diego below and change your mapping to:

```
public class OrderDetailMap : ClassMap<OrderDetail> {
    public OrderDetailMap() {
        Table("OrderDetail");

        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.Product, "ProductID")
            .KeyReference(x => x.OrderHeader, "HeaderID");

        Version(x => x.CreatedOn).Column("CreatedOn").Generated.Always();
    }
}
```

The code you have in your above mapping of OrderDetails is what is causing you the error "Invalid index 2 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=2."

```
References<OrderHeader>(x => x.OrderHeader, "HeaderID").ForeignKey().Not.Nullable().Fetch.Join();
References<Product>(x => x.Product, "ProductID").ForeignKey().Not.Nullable();
```

Comment: I tried, it still does not generate insert statement against my OrderDetail table.

Comment: You are right, I removed addtional References in OrderDetail mapping, my code moved forward one more step. NH generated SQL statement like: UPDATE OrderDetail SET  WHERE ProductID = @p0 AND HeaderID = @p1 AND CreatedOn = @p2, which has syntax error. After I remved Version mapping from OrderDetail, everything works fine now. Just not sure why Version mapping here will cause the funny thing.

Answer (score 1):

well firstly, your OrderDetail is mapped wrongly: You may not map one column multiple times. Here you both assign it for composite-id as well as have a many-to-one. Your composite-id can (and should) have 2 many-to-one properties and not just value properties.

This is evident in your last comment on Diego's answer, see also [IndexOutOfRangeException Deep in the bowels of NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298026/indexoutofrangeexception-deep-in-the-bowels-of-nhibernate/2311256#2311256)

Secondly you are setting an `inverse` on the `OrderHeader.Details` collection which if i remember correctly means method1 would not cause an insert on the OrderDetail

Comment: isn't Inverse() used to let ther other side to control the creation?