# NHibernate: Mapping a single column twice

Tags: c#, nhibernate, data-binding

Is it possible to map one column twice using NHibernate?

```
<property name="CustomerID" index="IX_Customer" not-null="true" />
<many-to-one name="Customer" column="customerid" class="Customer" fetch="join" />
```

I need to have the raw ID in order to bind a WinForms control which only supports Binding using a value (instead of the Item itself).

```
 myControl.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", bs, "CustomerID", true));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just modify

```
<property name="CustomerID" index="IX_Customer" insert="false" update="false" not-null="true" />
```

Comment: Hm, is this working without getting an error like Jaguar mentioned?

Comment: Didn't had any error since I used this solution, thanks! It's more a workaround for the moment, since I want to get rid of all those ID's..

Answer (score 0):

You can but it's a really bad idea.
see [IndexOutOfRangeException Deep in the bowels of NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298026/indexoutofrangeexception-deep-in-the-bowels-of-nhibernate)

you should find some other way to bind the id from the entity to your control