# Fluent Mapping Many-Many with sorting

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to get a many to many relationship to work using Fluent Nhibernate.

I have a `Product` and a `RelatedProduct` Table

```
Product {Id, Name...}
ProductRelated{Id, ProductId, RelatedProductId, relOrder}
```

and a `Product` class

The mapping looks like

```
  HasManyToMany(x => x.RelatedProducts)
                .Table("ProductRelated")
                .ReadOnly()
                .ChildOrderBy("relOrder asc")
                .ParentKeyColumn("ProductId")
                .ChildKeyColumn("RelatedProductId");
```

When a query is done for `Product` and the `RelatedProducts` are lazy loaded I can see that the sorting is applied correctly using the `relOrder` on the join table.

```
Session.Query<Product>()
       .FetchMany(p => p.Categories)
       .FetchMany(p => p.Departments)
```

Once I add in eager loading of the related products NHibernate tries to sort by a `relOrder` column on the product itself instead of on the join table.

```
Session.Query<Product>()
       .FetchMany(p => p.Categories)
       .FetchMany(p => p.Departments)
       .FetchMany(p => p.RelatedProducts)
```

Any ideas of whats going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to answer your question *what's going on here?*, I would say, you are using: "not-together fitting features" of NHibernate.

A snippet from documentation [6.6. Sorted Collections](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-sorted):

> Setting the `order-by` attribute tells NHibernate ...
>
> *Note: that lookup operations on these collections are very slow if they contain more than a few elements.*
>
> **Note: that the value of the order-by attribute is an SQL ordering, not a HQL ordering!**

So, this could be applied only for "standard" lazy loading, becuase this kind of a feature is applied only on a DB side. It is **not** managing order **in the memory**.

And the eager fetching, as the counter-part, is a different way how to generate and issue the SQL Statement to DB.

So, eager and `order-by` will never work together.

*

My NOTE: I simply have to append this. *I can't help myself*

I.

The Eager fetching is the feature which should be avoided *(I never use it, but it's me)*. There is a better solution and it is setting the `BatchSize()`, which will reduce the 1+N into 1+(a few) and will keep all the (lazy) featrues, including `order-by`. Check these if interested:

- [NHibernate QueryOver with Fetch resulting multiple sql queries and db hits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284228/)
- [Is this the right way to eager load child collections in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199159/)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419988/

`BatchSize()` is supported for `HasManyToMany` as well: [ToManyBase](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Mapping/ToManyBase.cs):

```
/// <summary>Specify the select batch size </summary>
/// <param name="size">Batch size</param>
public T BatchSize(int size) { ...
```

II.

The `many-to-many` mapping, while fancy at first look, is not the way I'd suggest. Try to rethink your model and introduce the *first-level-citizen*: `PairingEntity` - for the pairing object. It will then use `many-to-one` and `one-to-many` mapping which could give us more... e.g. improved querying like Subqueries... try to check these:

- [How to create NHibernate HasManyToMany relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135770/)
- [many-to-many with extra columns nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563082/)
- [Nhibernate: How to represent Many-To-Many relationships with One-to-Many relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510748/)